# jquery to vanilla js; each loop of html tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, dom

So this is my current jquery code, which I would like in vanilla js.

```
var elems = [];

$("*").not('script, style, iframe').each(function() {
    elems.push($(this)[0]);
});
```

the closest alternative I found was
`document.getElementsByTagName("*")`
but that still has iframe, style, and script tags, which I don't want in my array.

Also, I can't just remove them by their tag name specifically, as they might have an id or a class associated with them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option would be to use a CSS selector along with the [`.querySelectorAll()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).

Since CSS has a [`:not()` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not), you could use that to negate the `script`, `style`, and `iframe` elements.

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('*:not(script):not(style):not(iframe');
```

In the snippet above, `elements` would be a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) containing a collection of the selected elements.

Comment: That worked perfectly! I'll mark as correct as soon as stackoverflow allows me to, Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Yes, that is what I was using anyway, a nodelist.